# how to open page inner from iframe and add nav-active class to respective page menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Hello friends i am working with in iframe, i am getting a problem with menu. I want to add nav-active class inner from an iframe. When i click view more button inner from iframe then respective page should open and respective page menu should have nav-active class. This class should add to only one li element in menu.I have attached image .I have tried following code for menu but not working for me.

```
function myFunction() {
  event.stopPropagation()
  $("li.test1").addClass("nav-expanded");
  $("li.test2").addClass("nav-active");
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem thanx in advance.

[website view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88zlB.png)

Answer (score 0):

With iframes it is not possible to do what you are asking if the iframe and your domain are different. It cannot be done cross domain.

**The same origin policy prevents a document or script loaded from one origin from getting or setting properties of a document from another origin. This policy dates all the way back to Netscape Navigator 2.0.**

Browsers have tightened the security on cross frame domain scripting due to the potential of misuse and hacks.

However if the iframe is from the same domain; the elements can be accessed easily, like so:

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find("li.test1").addClass("nav-expanded");
```

Comment: Neelam This function is not working for me . which functioni am using  is working like i want but not removing nav-active or nav-expanded class from its siblings in menu

Comment: My code was just an example, you would need to change `#iFrame` to be the ID of the iframe or target it using the class. Can you share some HTML so I can see it too? Also you have not declared `removeClass` in your JS; your JS has declared `addClass` only so it will not remove any classes as it doesn't know they have to be removed. Share more code please.